# cx_Oracle insert large XMLType value

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have the following schema:

```
create table tc (c1 clob, c2 SYS.XMLTYPE)
```

to which I try to insert using this code:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn_to = cx_Oracle.connect('user', '...', 'dbserver:1521/ENGR')

cur_to = conn_to.cursor()

insert_sql = 'insert into tc values (:val, :xmlval)'

cur_to.prepare(insert_sql)

cur_to.setinputsizes(val=cx_Oracle.CLOB, xmlval=8196)
cur_to.execute(insert_sql, {'val':('a' * 98196), 'xmlval':('<xml>' + '<inner/>' * 450 + '</xml>')})
conn_to.commit()
```

producing an XML object of about 4963 characters.
However if I change that 450 to 500, things no longer work, I get back an error

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

The limit seems to be around 5000, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, wait, here it is:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn_to = cx_Oracle.connect('user', '...', 'dbserver:1521/ENGR') 

cur_to = conn_to.cursor()

insert_sql = 'insert into tc values (:val, xmltype(:xmlval))' # need to wrap with xmltype() !

cur_to.setinputsizes(val=cx_Oracle.CLOB, xmlval=cx_Oracle.CLOB) # need to set to cx_Oracle.CLOB!
s =  ('<xml>' + '<inner/>' * 550 + '</xml>')
cur_to.execute(insert_sql, val = s, xmlval = s)

conn_to.commit()
```